# Memory profiling and search for memory leak

Tags: debugging, node.js, memory, profiling, node-inspector

I have a memory leak on one of the part of my node.js application.

I know that there is node-inspector module for debugging and he has a profiling tab but it looks like this module is no longer maintained(last commit 6 month ago) and not working for profiling on my osx and node.js 0.6.15.

Is there any other good and easy to use memory profiling tool for node.js?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Nodetime](http://nodetime.com). It takes heap snapshots via V8's built-in heap profiler and tries to present it so that it is easy to find leaking properties and variables. More in this post http://nodetime.com/blog/detecting-memory-leaks-in-nodejs-apps. Installing Nodetime is super easy. Just `npm install nodetime` and then `require('nodetime').profile()` before all other require statements.

Comment: Thanks. Looks nice and i'll try it.

But problem already fixed long time ago...